# Regex - how to match multiple properly quoted substrings

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use a Regex to extract quote-wrapped strings from within a (C#) string which is a comma-separated list of such strings. I need to extract all properly quoted substrings, and ignore those that are missing a quote  mark

eg given this string

"animal,dog,cat","ecoli, verification,"streptococcus"

I need to extract "animal,dog,cat" and "streptococcus".

I've tried various regex solutions in this forum but they all seem to find the first substring only, or incorrectly match "ecoli, verification," and ignore "streptococcus"

Is this solvable?

TIA

Comment: I doubt it can be solved. Almost all hints for this type of issue sound like "fix the source".

Comment: Even if you can parse it with a general programming language, you need more precise rule to define whether this is `"ecoli, verification,"` followed by a syntax error, or misquoted `"ecoli, verification` followed by properly quoted `"streptococcus"`.

Comment: could you provide more input strings? Maybe there is kind of pattern only visible in couple examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
"(?>[^",]*(?>,[^",]+)*)"
```

**Explanation:**

```
"        # Match a starting quote
(?>      # Capture in an atomic group to avoid catastrophic backtracking:
 [^",]*  # - any number of characters except commas or quotes
 (?>     # - optionally followed by another (atomic) group:
  ,      #   - which starts with a comma
  [^",]+ #   - and contains at least one character besides comma or quotes.
 )*      # - (as said above, that group is optional but may occur many times)
)        # End of the outer atomic group
"        # Match a closing quote
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yH9tG7/1).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string input = "\"animal,dog,cat\",\"ecoli, verification,\"streptococcus\"";
string pattern = "\"([^\"]+?[^,])\"";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

P.S. But I agree with the commentators: fix the source.

Comment: @DmitryPolyakov - [Lazy quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification) to improve performance.

Comment: The source is a human being editing the string and accidently deleting a " mark. if anyone can tell me how to fix the source you'll make me happy!